# How to get the next node with js in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="logo.png" onclick="getNextTableNode(this)">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table></table>
```

I can get the fist tableNode with js code

```
  function getNextTableNode(imgNode)
 { 
    tableNode1 = imgNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
 }
```

but how can I get the next tableNode? I do not want to use id or name. I have tried:

```
tableNode2 = tableNode1.nextSibling;
```

but it didn't work. Can anyone help?Thanks in advance

Comment: getNextTableNode(this),imgNode == this

Comment: Instead of using imgNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode to get the table node, you can use jQuery and do: `$(imgNode).closest('table')` and `$(imgNode).closest('table').next()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser adds a `<tbody>` node to the dom, regardless of whether one was included in the html. You'll need an extra `.parentNode` to get the table element.

Once you have the table element, use `nextElementSibling`:

```
tableNode2 = tableNode1.nextElementSibling;
```

Use `nextSibling` as a fallback for older browsers:

```
tableNode2 = tableNode1.nextElementSibling || tableNode1.nextSibling;
```

Comment: Remove the `()`. It's not a method.

Comment: In case you are wondering why you need nextElementSibling instead of nextSibling:  http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2014/01/04/secret-covert-hush-hush-white-space-in-the-dom-exposed.aspx

Comment: has polyfil examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling

Answer (score 2):

Create a couple utilities for getting an ancestor and sibling by tag name:

```
function closestParent(node, tag) {
    tag = (tag + "").toUpperCase();
    while (node && (node = node.parentNode) && node.nodeName !== tag)
       ;
    return node;
}
function nextSibling(node, tag) { 
    tag = (tag + "").toUpperCase();
    while (node && (node = node.nextSibling) && node.nodeName !== tag)
        ;
    return node;
}
```

---

Then use the utilities like this:

```
function getNextTableNode(node) {
    return nextSibling(closestParent(node, "table"), "table");
}
```

This provides very broad browser compatibility.

Comment: Good answer. I was going to add something along these lines as well.